# C enum using in c++ file

Tags: c++, c

### mode.h  :: from c

```
typedef enum Mode_t
{
    MODE_READ       = 0,
    MODE_WRITE      = 1,
    MODE_READ_WRITE = 2
}Mode_T;
int callfunc(int, Mode_T);
```

### mode.cpp

```
#include "mode.h"
extern "C" int callfunc(int, Mode_T);

int run()
{
   callfunc(2, MODE_WRITE);
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

> `Mode_T` has not been declared.

I tried using `extern` for the `enum` as well but then it gave the following error :

> **Error:** use of enum 'Mode_t' without previous declaration

How to use `C` enums in `C++` file ?

Comment: what compiler You use? Ancient C has not enums, but moderd standard yes. Without include will not work, btw

Comment: Did you include the header file in `mode.cpp`? Otherwise, how would it else know about `Mode_T`?

Comment: Also, if you include `mode.h` in a C++ source file, you need to have `extern "C"` in the header file for the function.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. It's unclear which file includes what.

Comment: Did you include the `mode.h` file in the `mode.cpp` ?

Comment: yes, I have included mode.h, edited to quested

Comment: Can you please show us the *complete* and *full* error? Copy-paste it, including any possible informational notes, and without any modifications or edits.

Comment: /home/prakash/CalenderAndSchedule/a9_core_code/packages/Schedule/src/SchedulTask.cpp:59:46: error: 'Mode_t' has not been declared
 extern "C" int Open_Queue(int*, char const*, Mode_t);

Comment: So the code you show here is not at all the same as the code you compile and/or the error you get is not the error you show in in the comment is not the error you show in your question.

Comment: yes but similar stuff i am doing there, since the whole code is large i can't copy paste

Comment: @Vineet OK, please [edit] your question and put the exact error message you get _there_

Comment: I am able to call function properly, even its getting linked properly with the use of extern "C", but with enums i am facing error, if same enum i declare, it gives multiple declarion for the enum name

Comment: Try `extern "C" {\n#include "mode.h"\n}`, where "\n" stand for new line

Comment: @Phantom, it working, thanks

Comment: You know that C/C++ is case sensitive, right? `Mode_T` and `Mode_t` are not the same thing. That’s the only thing my brain’s compiler finds for the first glance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to use C enums in C++ file ?

Just like all C declarations, you must use `extern "C"`.

You can put it around the include directive for example:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "mode.h"
}
```

A common pattern is to use

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

at the beginning and the end of a header file itself in order to make the header usable in both languages without having to know what language that header uses.

Comment: #ifdef __cplusplus I am using but not for the header calls, only for the functions might be due to that